# How to convert 12-Jan-2016 like date string in javascript to 2016-01-12 00:00:00

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

How to convert 12-Jan-2016 like date string in javascript to 2016-01-12 00:00:00,

I am looking at moment js but there seems no options like and also I tried js date function but is is returning invalid date.

Any idea what i am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to reformat the string, then don't bother with dates:

```js
function reformatDateString(ds) {
   var months = {jan:'01',feb:'02',mar:'03',apr:'04',may:'05',jun:'06',
                 jul:'07',aug:'08',sep:'09',oct:'10',nov:'11',dec:'12'};
  var b = ds.split('-');
  return b[2] + '-' + months[b[1].toLowerCase()] + '-' + b[0] + ' 00:00:00';
}

document.write(reformatDateString('12-Jan-2016'));
```

However, if you actually need to parse the string to a Date, then do that and format the string separately:

```js
function parseDMMMY(s) {
  var months = {jan:0,feb:1,mar:2,apr:3,may:4,jun:5,
                jul:6,aug:7,sep:8,oct:9,nov:10,dec:11};
  var b = s.split(/-/);
  return new Date(b[2], months[b[1].toLowerCase()], b[0]);
}

document.write(parseDMMMY('16-Jan-2016'));

function formatDate(d) {
  function z(n){return ('0'+n).slice(-2)}
  return z(d.getDate()) + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getFullYear() + 
         ' ' + z(d.getHours()) + ':' + z(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + z(d.getSeconds());
}

document.write('<br>' + formatDate(parseDMMMY('16-Jan-2016')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) function and [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method:

```
var dateString = "12-Jan-2016";
var convertedFormat = moment(dateString, "DD-MMM-YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log(convertedFormat);
// this will display: 2016-01-12 00:00:00
```

Please be sure that `Jan` is a valid month in your locale.

Comment: thanks and +1 for your response over the same, I will try it

Answer (score 0):

I think this function might give you what you are searching for.

```
 def parseStringDate(String date,Boolean flagTime=false){
    def date
    def Format='yyyy-MM-dd'
    def datePart=_date.toString().substring(0,10)
    if (flagTime){
        date = datePart+" "+_date.toString().substring(11,19)
      Format=Format+" "+'HH:mm:ss'
    }else date = datePart
    return [date, Format]
}
```

Comment: You sure that's javascript?